# Angular $resource remove question mark from REST querystring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Hi i was wondering if anyone could help me change the format of my querystring. Currently it is in the following format:

```
/api/foo?id=AD12JK23
```

but how would I go about to changing it to the following format:

```
/api/foo/AD12JK23
```

my code is as follows:

```
.state('foo-details', { 
    url: '/foo-details/:fooRefrence'
    }
 })

var ref = $stateParams.fooRefrence;
        $scope.fooDetails = myApi.Foo.get(
            {
                 id: ref
            }
        );

.factory('myApi', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {

        Foo: $resource('/api/foos', {id: '@ref' },

    }
}])
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the resource reference for the appropriate way to do this.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage

I think if you write your resource url like this, it will solve the problem:

```
.factory('myApi', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        // Add :id at the end of the url
        // Also change @ref to @id, the word you use after @ is the same as 
        // the key of the object you use to call the resource with
        Foo: $resource('/api/foos/:id', {id: '@id' },

    }
}])
```